# Update UI - Multi user session updates ng-grid angularjs

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I'm using ng-grid extensively using angularjs. I tried to open two browser window sessions simulating multiple users.  If user "A" updates a record in a browser page, without refreshing manually how can i display a message or update the display of ng-grid for user "B" on the updated record?

Comment: You need to implement some support for real-time data on the server. I would implement it through web sockets (see [socket.io](http://socket.io/)) because they are easy to  use and fast.

Comment: $timeout, $watch has any role in it?. Because im sure if the ngmodel is updated, automatically the UI refreshes in angularjs.

Comment: Here is a related question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815226/how-to-design-a-multi-user-ajax-web-application-to-be-concurrently-safe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815226/how-to-design-a-multi-user-ajax-web-application-to-be-concurrently-safe)

Comment: Angular JS runs on the client, in the browser. Each browser window is sandboxed. One client is not aware of any other. It's only the server that is common for both clients. If you want to implement concurrency handling it has to be done on the server. (As an exception, with web sockets you can connect the clients, peer to peer, but you still need some logic on the server to initiate the peer to peer connection )